# Can my question be undownvoted?

Tags: discussion

I have received [undue superuser hate](https://superuser.com/questions/484225/who-coined-the-phrase-everything-is-a-file) (=down-votes).  Could you please undownvote it? Thanks

Comment: downvotes ≠ Super User "hate".

Comment: @Sathya in general, no.  But in this case, yes

Comment: @Sathya And why is this particular question downvoted?

Comment: no, you think it's hate (for what, I don't know) but no. Questions which aren't fit for the site get downvoted, and it's not because of hate, rather it's because the community's telling you the question's not a good fit

Comment: as for downvotes on this question, meta downvotes indicate "I don't agree".

Comment: If *you* were targeted, other questions of yours would also get heavily down voted. You haven't received a single down vote for your other posts though -- clearly, it's not you, *it's the question*. You probably were just unlucky enough to write a question that for some reason attracted some attention (by far most questions do not get 150 views in two days), and is unfit enough for the site that a large number of readers consider it worthy of a down vote.

Comment: @Daniel I should have written _my question received hate_.  Of course I myself cannot possibly receive hate (nobody knows me).

Comment: @Daniel anyway, I can't believe everybody voted down solely on formal grounds.

Comment: @HolySheet Regardless of what you believe, the votes have been cast. If you're not comfortable having your contributions critiqued and voted on, this site may not be for you. And at any rate, what do you hope to achieve with this meta post? As **slhck** explains below, votes cannot be retracted once locked in. Do you want moderators to go through every single person who downvoted and poll them individually for the reason, then determine if it qualifies as "formal grounds"? That's not how this site works. Just accept that the community didn't approve of your question and move on.

Comment: Your question is gone, but with pleasure I upvote this one +1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Down votes do not mean hate.** If you think they do, you might just take things too personally. If you yourself down vote others' posts because you hate the posts or the users behind them, well, I'm sorry to say that, but then Super User might not be the place for you.

Downvotes generally indicate that a post – in some way – is not a good fit for the site. It might be lacking research effort, it might be unclear, or it might simply be not constructive or off topic.

A question can be undownvoted from the person who downvoted it only after it has been edited. Otherwise, votes stay locked indefinitely. This is basically the only way a downvote could be removed.

One downvote stems from the system, which automatically happens when a question is closed as *off topic* or *not a real question*.

Comment: I guess the average non-constructive question does not receive that many down votes.  How do you explain the difference?  It's plain sanctioning.

Comment: @HolySheet they do. [Importing about millions of contacts into outlook](http://superuser.com/q/474177) Stop thinking you're being targetted. **You're not**.

Comment: @Sathya That's not exactly an average downvote count.  Besides that, a question by someone who gets punished for seeking help at spamming really proves my point. If outlook had crashed because of 1000 contacts, the question would not have been closed at all.

Comment: @HolySheet Questions with a lot of downvotes tend to be deleted, so the 'average' you can see tends to be positively skewed. Questions with negative scores are often closed for the same reason they are downvoted; closed questions can be voted to deletion by users with enough rep. Moderators can delete questions, and often will if they are bad enough. Flags for spam or offensive content (with is usually accompanied by a lot of downvotes) lead to deletion. Questions with negative scores are deleted after a certain amount of time, if unanswered. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/187228